# Angular component view doesn't list the complete NGRX state payload until refresh(F5)

Tags: angular, state, ngrx, payload

I got a problem with my component view. I have an Event model holding an array of Users. When i load the event i get this payload in the redux devtools. So all data we need is available in the payload. The problem is that im only able to list the users for the event when refreshing the page (f5). Do anyone see the problem in the code? I think that the problem is not within the state, because i get the correct data in the payload...

```
**payload**
title(pin):"Lasergame"
description(pin):"Bring shoes with you"
location(pin):"Interpool"
creatorId(pin):1
users(pin): {users..}     //here is the array which contains the users
id(pin):1
type(pin):"[API: /event] Load Event success"
```

This is the relevent piece of the html:

```
<div *ngIf="ev$ | async; let ev">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="tab-panel">
    <tabset class="member-tabset">
      <tab heading="Om evenemang">
        <h4 style="font-weight: bold;">Beskrivning</h4>
         <p>{{ ev.description }}</p>
          <ul *ngIf="ev.users"> 
           <li *ngFor="let item of ev.users">
            <p>
              {{ item.email }}
              {{ item.name }} 
            </p>
          </li>
           </ul> 
    </tabset>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is event.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

import { AppState } from 'src/app/core/state';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromEvent from '../../state/events';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Event, User } from 'src/app/shared/models';

import * as eventActions from '../../state/events';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'ex-event-detail',
  templateUrl: './event-detail.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styleUrls: ['./event-detail.component.scss']
})
export class EventDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  ev$: Observable<Event>;

  constructor(private store$: Store<AppState>, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.LoadEvent();
    console.log(this.ev$);
  }

  private LoadEvent(): void {
    this.store$.dispatch(new eventActions.LoadEvent(this.getClickedId()));
    this.ev$ = this.store$.pipe(select(fromEvent.getCurrentEvent));

  }

  private getClickedId() {
    var id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    return id;
  }

}
```

This is my ngrx code.

events.actions.ts

```js
export class LoadEvent implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.LOAD_EVENT;

  constructor(public payload: number) {}
}

export class LoadEventSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.LOAD_EVENT_SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: Event) {}
}
```

events.effects.ts

```js
  @Effect()
  loadEvent$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<eventsActions.LoadEvent>(eventsActions.ActionTypes.LOAD_EVENT),
    mergeMap((action: eventsActions.LoadEvent) =>
      this.eventResource.loadEvent(action.payload).pipe(
        map((event: Event) => new eventsActions.LoadEventSuccess(event)),
        catchError(err => of(new eventsActions.LoadEventError(err)))
     )
   )
 );
```

events.reducer.ts

```js
case eventsActions.ActionTypes.LOAD_EVENT_SUCCESS: {
  return adapter.addOne(action.payload, {
    ...state,
    selectedEventId: action.payload.id
  });
}
```

events.selectors.ts

```js
const { selectAll } = adapter.getSelectors();

export const selectState = (state: AppState) => state.event.evs;


export const getCurrentEventId = createSelector(selectState, state => 
state.selectedEventId)

export const getCurrentEvent = createSelector(selectState, getCurrentEventId, state =>         
state.entities[state.selectedEventId])
events.adapter.ts

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Event> = createEntityAdapter<Event>({
 selectId: (ev: Event) => ev.id
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `this.ev$ = this.store...` earlier, like in the constructor?

Comment: Also, I see that you're using `OnPush` strategy, and the change detector should be called whenever `ev$` emitted (`async` pipe mark the component for check). But, if the suggestion above doesn't help  (I think it will) you can call `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` inside a `tap` pipe on `ev$`. Usually, in my projects, I follow the container-presentation pattern, so that kind of problem doesn't happen so often.

Comment: I tried both of your solutions, but none of them worked.. :/ This is my constructor right now,                                                                                          
                                                                                                         constructor(private store$: Store<AppState>, private route: ActivatedRoute, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    
    this.ev$ = this.store$.pipe(select(fromEvent.getCurrentEvent), 
   tap(this.cdr.markForCheck));
  }

Comment: In this case, it seems that your ev$, for some reason isn't emitting at all. Where are you initializing this slice of the store? Is it in a lazy loaded module?

Comment: I posted my ngrx code below, maybe you can see something wrong in there. But there shouldnt be any problem because i get the correct data in the payload, and because its working when i refresh the page..

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past and the issue was that I was trying to use the store in a lazy loaded module before it was ready to use. It's not full similar to your case, but check if this slice is in the store when you use it. Maybe you can use a `setTimeout` to delay a little bit this part: `this.store$.dispatch(new eventActions.LoadEvent(this.getClickedId()));`

Comment: I see, maybe that is the problem. How should i do this the best way?

Comment: Just do something  like `setTimetout(() => this.LoadEvent(), 2000)` in your `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe to `activatedRoute.params` as below :

```js
export class EventDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription: Subscription;
  ev$: Observable<Event>;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private store$: Store<AppState>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ev$ = this.store$.pipe(select(fromEvent.getCurrentEvent));

    this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.store$.dispatch(new eventActions.LoadEvent(+id));
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

More details in [Accessing URL parameters in Angular: Snapshot vs Subscription](https://medium.com/@tiboprea/accessing-url-parameters-in-angular-snapshot-vs-subscription-efc4e70f9053).

Also it seems you have an issue with your `getCurrentEvent` selector, your code should be:

```js
const { selectIds, selectEntities } = adapter.getSelectors(getState);

export const getCurrentEvent = createSelector(
  selectEntities, getCurrentEventId, (entities, currentEventId) => {
    return entities[currentEventId])
})
```

in place of :

```js
export const getCurrentEvent = createSelector(selectState, 
  getCurrentEventId, state => state.entities[state.selectedEventId])
```

Comment: I tried your code but now i'm not able to see the details of a event, it doesn't load the LoadEvent in redux devtools..

Comment: Thank you, but i still need to reload the page to be able to list the users...

Comment: Have a you a new LoadEvent generated each time you change route ?

Comment: Yes, whenever i go into the event detail component, i use LoadEvent

Comment: You use LoadEvent or you see a new LoadEvent action generated in Dev Tools ?

Comment: Its a new generated LoadEvent action in Dev Tools, and if i change the url lfrom events/1 to events/2, everything works fine and the users is listed..

Comment: if you create a stackblitz env, I'll try to find your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is my ngrx code,

events.actions.ts

```
export class LoadEvent implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.LOAD_EVENT;

  constructor(public payload: number) {}
}

export class LoadEventSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.LOAD_EVENT_SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: Event) {}
}
```

events.effects.ts

```
  @Effect()
  loadEvent$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<eventsActions.LoadEvent>(eventsActions.ActionTypes.LOAD_EVENT),
    mergeMap((action: eventsActions.LoadEvent) =>
      this.eventResource.loadEvent(action.payload).pipe(
        map((event: Event) => new eventsActions.LoadEventSuccess(event)),
        catchError(err => of(new eventsActions.LoadEventError(err)))
     )
   )
 );
```

events.reducer.ts

```
case eventsActions.ActionTypes.LOAD_EVENT_SUCCESS: {
  return adapter.addOne(action.payload, {
    ...state,
    selectedEventId: action.payload.id
  });
}
```

events.selectors.ts

```
const { selectAll } = adapter.getSelectors();

export const selectState = (state: AppState) => state.event.evs;


export const getCurrentEventId = createSelector(selectState, state => 
state.selectedEventId)

export const getCurrentEvent = createSelector(selectState, getCurrentEventId, state =>         
state.entities[state.selectedEventId])
```

events.adapter.ts

```
export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Event> = createEntityAdapter<Event>({
 selectId: (ev: Event) => ev.id
});
```